# Here Maps Auto-Suggest endpoint change language

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

When using the HERE Maps Places Autosuggest endpoint, we get language based on country of origin of the place for vicinity details. Even though we are setting the header to `Accept-Language: 'en-US'` It still returns a different language.

For example, when we are using the API to search for places in Dubai, we get the vicinity details in Arabic. We are using the following endpoint: 
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest

So, currently the maps is showing arabic as default language for the results. How do we change it to English?

Comment: What is your question about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using an older version of the places API. This one works with converting the language to English:

```
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=25.2048,55.2708&q=hospital&limit=2&apiKey=YOURAPIKEY&lang=en-US
```